# SPListItem.Delete or SPListItem.Recycle, which one was called?

Tags: 2010, event-receivers

In an ItemDeleting event receiver, is there a way to find out whether SPListItem.Delete or SPListItem.Recycle was called?

I would like to write different things to my log here...

Answer (score 1):

I thought the answer was to check if the document was in the recycle bin:

```
private bool DocumentWasRecycled(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    Guid itemGuid = properties.ListItem.UniqueId;
    SPRecycleBinItem recycledItem = null;
    try
    {
        recycledItem = properties.Web.RecycleBin.GetItemById(itemGuid);
    }
    catch { }
    return recycledItem != null;
}
```

But the problem is that if I do it in ItemAdding, it hasn't been put in the recycle bin yet, and if I do it in ItemAdded, I can no longer get the ID of the item...

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution to my question

```
public override void ItemDeleted(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    string[] splittedBeforeUrl = properties.BeforeUrl.Split('/');
    string fileName = splittedBeforeUrl.Last();
    string filePath = properties.BeforeUrl.Replace(fileName, "").TrimEnd('/');
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        foreach (SPRecycleBinItem item in properties.Web.RecycleBin)
        {
            if (item.ItemType == SPRecycleBinItemType.File)
            {
                if (fileName.Contains(item.Title) && item.DirName.Contains(filePath))
                {
                    LogDeleteEvent(filePath, fileName);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    base.ItemDeleting(properties);
}
```

But in my log, I also need some fields from the SPListItem, which is null in the ItemDeleted event. So I guess there is no solution...